# Best way to implement address book autocompletion on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-data, memory-management, autocomplete, addressbook

I'm wondering what is the best (fastest and simplest) way to have a textfield
auto complete with iPhone's address book contacts information.

Would access the address book each time a key is pressed fast enough ?
Or do I have to load everything in my own local database (CoreData typically) ?
Another way would be to load everything in memory at each app launch. Any experience
regarding the access speed of the adress book ?

ADDED: I'd like to avoid having to load a local copy of the address book content because it's not only more code to write but you also need to sync your local copy when address book is modified.

Comment: What kind of contacts information will appear in the auto complete fields ?

Comment: Names (first and last), email or phone number. The user should be able to use any of those details to select a contact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For super fast character by character retrieval, the approach you need is called a [Directed acyclic word graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph).

Answer (score 1):

> Would access the address book each
>   time a key is pressed fast enough ?

Probably not for large books but test it an see. You could call `ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName` with each additional character and see what pops up. You would most likely need to require a minimum number of characters e.g. 3 before performing the search because otherwise you would get a lot of returns for each the first character.

However, I don't think there are functions for phone numbers and addresses.

The alternative would be to create a tree data structure with letters and numbers that would branch out to a leaf containing an ABRecordID of a particular AddressBook entry. Using Core Data relationships is a quick and easy way to do that. Of course, you would have to update your tree continuously.