# auto complete a search

Tags: iphone, ios6

I have searched the questions so far, and it seems that most auto complete questions are about the console.

How can we auto complete a search and load it like the image below.  I am new to xcode, so if you have instructions on what I need to do to get it to look like this, then I will appreciate it.

Basically I have an empty table cell, when i touch it to edit, a search box should come up (at the top), and as soon as I type a, all the values for a show up below in individual cells.  I can select a cell when I see the value, and it will take me back to the original table and input that value into that cell.

What is the structure after i click the initial cell to bring up the search box

Auto complete with cells?

After this, I imagine I store the value of the variable, and assign it to the cell it originated from.

Attached is an image for reference.

Thank you in advance.[image]

PS - The list to auto complete from has a few thousand values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For several thousand entries it's unlikely Core Data will give you good performance. Instead you'll need to load the data as a Directed Acyclic Word Graph (DAWG). See other answers on this for further info.

[Directed acyclic graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920371/directed-acyclic-graph/5990451#5990451)

[Best way to implement address book autocompletion on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230976/best-way-to-implement-address-book-autocompletion-on-iphone/5244518#5244518)

Comment: Thank you, will look at the links and read about DAG,              also will directed acyclic graph work to sort and index 10,000+ recipe entries very quickly?  Is core data sufficient?  The recipes are stored in the app

Comment: when I did this I had a flat file that held all the names for fast table browsing. I used an in-memory DAWG for name searching. The in-memory DAWG was loaded on app startup from an index file that I generated before-hand